# glob exclude pattern

Tags: python, glob

I have a directory with a bunch of files inside: `eee2314`, `asd3442` ... and `eph`.

I want to exclude all files that start with `eph` with the `glob` function.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 300, accepted):

The pattern rules for glob are not regular expressions. Instead, they follow standard Unix path expansion rules. There are only a few special characters: two different wild-cards, and character ranges are supported [from [pymotw: glob – Filename pattern matching](https://pymotw.com/2/glob/)].

So you can exclude some files with patterns.
For example to exclude manifests files (files starting with `_`) with glob, you can use:

```
files = glob.glob('files_path/[!_]*')
```

Comment: This must be at official documentation, please somebody add this to https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html#glob.glob

Comment: Note that glob patterns can't directly fullfill the requirement set out by the OP: to exclude only files that start with `eph` but can start with anything else. `[!e][!p][!h]` will filter out files that start with `eee` for example.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich it is in the documentation for fnmatch: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch

Answer (score 113):

You can deduct sets and cast it back as a list:

```
list(set(glob("*")) - set(glob("eph*")))
```

Comment: Really interesting solution! But my case is going to be extremely slow to make a read twice. Also if the content of a folder is big on an network directory, is going to be slow again. But in any case, really handy.

Comment: Your operating system should cache filesystem requests so not so bad :)

Comment: Tried this myself, I just got TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: @TomBusby Try converting them to sets:
`set(glob("*")) - set(glob("eph*"))`

(and notice * at the end of "eph*")

Comment: Just as a side note, glob returns lists and not sets, but this kind of operation only works on sets, hence why [neutrinus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1216074/neutrinus) cast it. If you need it to remain a list, simply wrap the entire operation in a cast: `list(set(glob("*")) - set(glob("eph")))`

Comment: Genius answer!!

Comment: really annoying that `glob` does take `pathlib` objects. Now your beautiful answer has so many parenthesis it makes me puke. `tasks_folder = set(glob(str(data_path / '*'))) - set(glob(str(data_path / "f_avg")))
`

Answer (score 62):

You can't exclude patterns with the `glob` function, globs only allow for *inclusion* patterns. [Globbing syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Syntax) is very limited (even a `[!..]` character class *must* match a character, so it is an *inclusion pattern* for every character that is not in the class).

You'll have to do your own filtering; a list comprehension usually works nicely here:

```
files = [fn for fn in glob('somepath/*.txt') 
         if not os.path.basename(fn).startswith('eph')]
```

Comment: Use ``iglob`` here to avoid storing the full list in memory

Comment: @Hardex: internally, `iglob` produces lists *anyway*; all you do is lazily evaluate the filter. It won't help to reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: @Hardex: if you use a glob in the *directory name* then you'd have a point, then at most one `os.listdir()` result is kept in memory as you iterate. But `somepath/*.txt` has to read all filenames in one directory in memory, then reduce that list down to only those that match.

Comment: you're right, it's not that important, but in stock CPython, ``glob.glob(x) = list(glob.iglob(x))``. Not much of an overhead but still good to know.

Comment: Doesn't this iterate twice?. Once through the files to get the list and the second through the list itself? If so, is it not possible to do it in one iteration?

Comment: @Ridhuvarshan: No, the list comprehension does just the one iteration. But if all you are going to do with the `files` list is iterate, then you could just as well make it a generator expression.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't this be `glob.glob()`? At least that's how I got it working.

Comment: @FelixPhl: depends on how you import it. If you use `from glob import glob` then the global name `glob` in your module is the function. If you use `import glob` then the global name is the module, and you need to use `glob.glob()`.

Answer (score 16):

Compared with `glob`, I recommend `pathlib`. Filtering one pattern is very simple.

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(YOUR_PATH)
filtered = [x for x in p.glob("**/*") if not x.name.startswith("eph")]
```

And if you want to filter a more complex pattern, you can define a function to do that, just like:

```py
def not_in_pattern(x):
    return (not x.name.startswith("eph")) and not x.name.startswith("epi")


filtered = [x for x in p.glob("**/*") if not_in_pattern(x)]
```

Using that code, you can filter all files that start with `eph` or start with `epi`.

Answer (score 12):

Late to the game but you could alternatively just apply a python `filter` to the result of a `glob`:

```
files = glob.iglob('your_path_here')
files_i_care_about = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("eph"), files)
```

or replacing the lambda with an appropriate regex search, etc...

EDIT: I just realized that if you're using full paths the `startswith` won't work, so you'd need a regex

```
In [10]: a
Out[10]: ['/some/path/foo', 'some/path/bar', 'some/path/eph_thing']

In [11]: filter(lambda x: not re.search('/eph', x), a)
Out[11]: ['/some/path/foo', 'some/path/bar']
```

Answer (score 7):

How about skipping the particular file while iterating over all the files in the folder!
Below code would skip all excel files that start with 'eph'

```
import glob
import re
for file in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    if re.match('eph.*\.xlsx',file):
        continue
    else:
        #do your stuff here
        print(file)
```

This way you can use more complex regex patterns to include/exclude a particular set of files in a folder.

Answer (score 4):

More generally, to exclude files that don't comply with some shell regexp, you could use module `fnmatch`:

```
import fnmatch

file_list = glob('somepath')    
for ind, ii in enumerate(file_list):
    if not fnmatch.fnmatch(ii, 'bash_regexp_with_exclude'):
        file_list.pop(ind)
```

The above will first generate a list from a given path and next pop out the files that won't satisfy the regular expression with the desired constraint.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have this directory structure:

```
.
├── asd3442
├── eee2314
├── eph334
├── eph_dir
│   ├── asd330
│   ├── eph_file2
│   ├── exy123
│   └── file_with_eph
├── eph_file
├── not_eph_dir
│   ├── ephXXX
│   └── with_eph
└── not_eph_rest
```

You can use full globs to filter full path results with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and a generator for the top level directory:

```
i_want=(fn for fn in Path(path_to).glob('*') if not fn.match('**/*/eph*'))

>>> list(i_want)
[PosixPath('/tmp/test/eee2314'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/asd3442'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/not_eph_rest'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/not_eph_dir')]
```

The pathlib method [match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.match) uses globs to match a path object; The glob `'**/*/eph*'` is any full path that leads to a file with a name starting with `'eph'`.

Alternatively, you can use the `.name` attribute with `name.startswith('eph')`:

```
i_want=(fn for fn in Path(path_to).glob('*') if not fn.name.startswith('eph'))
```

If you want only files, no directories:

```
i_want=(fn for fn in Path(path_to).glob('*') if fn.is_file() and not fn.match('**/*/eph*'))
# [PosixPath('/tmp/test/eee2314'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/asd3442'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/not_eph_rest')]
```

The same method works for recursive globs:

```
i_want=(fn for fn in Path(path_to).glob('**/*') 
           if fn.is_file() and not fn.match('**/*/eph*'))

# [PosixPath('/tmp/test/eee2314'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/asd3442'), 
   PosixPath('/tmp/test/not_eph_rest'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/eph_dir/asd330'), 
   PosixPath('/tmp/test/eph_dir/file_with_eph'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/eph_dir/exy123'), 
   PosixPath('/tmp/test/not_eph_dir/with_eph')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the accepted answer, you can't exclude patterns with glob, so the following is a method to filter your glob result.

The accepted answer is probably the best pythonic way to do things but if you think list comprehensions look a bit ugly and want to make your code maximally numpythonic anyway (like I did) then you can do this (but note that this is probably less efficient than the list comprehension method):

```
import glob

data_files = glob.glob("path_to_files/*.fits")

light_files = np.setdiff1d( data_files, glob.glob("*BIAS*"))
light_files = np.setdiff1d(light_files, glob.glob("*FLAT*"))
```

(In my case, I had some image frames, bias frames, and flat frames all in one directory and I just wanted the image frames)

Answer (score 0):

If the position of the character **isn't** important, that is for example to exclude manifests files (wherever it is found `_`) with `glob` and `re` - [regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), you can use:

```py
import glob
import re
for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    if re.match(r'.*\_.*', file):
        continue
    else:
        print(file)
```

Or with in a more elegant way - `list comprehension`

```py
filtered = [f for f in glob.glob('*.txt') if not re.match(r'.*\_.*', f)]

for mach in filtered:
    print(mach)
```

Answer (score 0):

To exclude exact word you may want to implement *custom regex directive*, which you will then replace by empty string before `glob` processing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import glob
import re

# glob (or fnmatch) does not support exact word matching. This is custom directive to overcome this issue
glob_exact_match_regex = r"\[\^.*\]"
path = "[^exclude.py]*py"  # [^...] is a custom directive, that excludes exact match

# Process custom directive
try:  # Try to parse exact match direction
    exact_match = re.findall(glob_exact_match_regex, path)[0].replace('[^', '').replace(']', '')
except IndexError:
    exact_match = None
else:  # Remove custom directive
    path = re.sub(glob_exact_match_regex, "", path)
paths = glob.glob(path)
# Implement custom directive
if exact_match is not None:  # Exclude all paths with specified string
    paths = [p for p in paths if exact_match not in p]

print(paths)
```

Answer (score 0):

`import glob`
`import re`

""" This is a path that should be excluded """
`EXCLUDE = "/home/koosha/Documents/Excel"`

`files = glob.glob("/home/koosha/Documents/**/*.*" , recursive=True)`
`for file in files:`
     `if re.search(EXCLUDE,file):`
                `pass`
    `else:`
                `print(file)`