# How does glob negation work?

Tags: linux, gulp, gruntjs, glob

I'm using gulp and don't understand the method of the following glob pattern:

```
'./bower_components/**/!(*.min).css'
```

It selects all the css files except the min postfixed ones. What would have it compiled to if it had been regex expression?

I understood why `'./bower_components/**/*!(.min).css'` form does not work, but I still don't understand why there is no need to put a asterisk before `.css` like:

```
'./bower_components/**/!(*.min)*.css'
```

The asterisk before the .min reads the chars or could you explain me?
How did this pattern find the match before the negation bracket if the star is in the bracket? I image it as a regex.
Thank you.

Comment: Will there ever be a case when there are characters between ".min" and ".css"?

Comment: no, but the question would be about the understanding this pattern, not the result.
How did this pattern find the match before the negation bracket if the star is in the bracket? I image it as a regex.

Comment: "I image it as a regex." Well, that's the problem. It's not a regex, it's a glob. First you glob it, then you see if anything matches that shouldn't.

Comment: the result of it is correct but how does this syntax work? 
'./bower_components/**/!(*.min).css' runs twice?

Comment: It globs './bower_components/**/*.css' and removes anything that shouldn't match.

Comment: Does it take the asterisk inside from the brackets of !(*.min)?

Comment: No, it puts the asterisk *because* of the extglob.

Answer (score 6):

I found this stackoverflow answer related to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36295481/2929207

Applied to this question it would be as follows:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('./bower_components/**/[!*.min].css')
```