# How to exclude some files when reading with glob.glob()?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, glob

I am reading some files using glob.glob(). I want to read all the files with names 123*.txt except those with 123*error.txt. Also, is there a way to print the filenames in the for loop, which is inside pd.concat()?

```
fields = ['StudentID', 'Grade']
path= 'C:/script_testing/'

parse = lambda f: pd.read_csv(f, usecols=fields)
table3 = pd.concat(
[parse(f) for f in glob.glob('C:/script_testing/**/*.txt', recursive=True)]
).pipe(lambda d: pd.crosstab(d.StudentID, d.Grade))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this pattern

```
files = glob.glob('C:/script_testing/**/123*[!error].txt', recursive=True)
```

Then proceed

```
fields = ['StudentID', 'Grade']
path= 'C:/script_testing/'

parse = lambda f: pd.read_csv(f, usecols=fields)
table3 = pd.concat(
    [parse(f) for f in files]
).pipe(lambda d: pd.crosstab(d.StudentID, d.Grade))
```

---

**Reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36295481/2336654)**

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I thought I tried all those combinations, but may be not.