# python glob exclude pattern in the file name

Tags: python, glob

This should be simple but I could not get it working. 
I would like to list the files in a directory by excluding files containing a certain pattern using glob.glob in python.

The files in my directory are:

`lh.Hip.nii, lh.IPL.nii, lh.LTC.nii, rh.Hip.nii, rh.IPL.nii, rh.LTC.nii`

and I would like to list the files by excluding the ones containing "Hip" in the file name:

`lh.IPL.nii, lh.LTC.nii, rh.IPL.nii, rh.LTC.nii`

There is a similar question [glob exclude pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638040/glob-exclude-pattern) and the solution only works if I want to exclude files starting with a certain pattern but it does not work in my case.

Any ideas?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read how to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can get all file names with `glob` then filter them with list comprehension, like so:

```py
[i for i in glob("*.nii") if i.split('.')[1] != 'Hip']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works and for now I am going to use this solution. I am still wondering though whether there is a glob wildcard to do this exclusion.

Comment: @IlkayIsik I read the comments in the link that you mentioned and most of them say that `glob` filter are mostly made for simple inclusion and not exclusion. I also tried some patterns but non of them worked

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
result = []
files = glob.glob('*')
for f in files : 
    if 'Hip' not in f : 
        result.append(f)
```

The result in your case is : `['lh.IPL.nii', 'lh.LTC.nii', 'rh.IPL.nii', 'rh.LTC.nii']`