# Return the filenames that end with *.tif, but don't end with *_mask.tif

Tags: python

With Python 3.7.7, I want to get the list of all the images that don't end with `*_mask.tif`.

In the path there are images that end with `*.tif` and with `*_mask.tif`. But the following code returns all of them.

```
# Read all the brain images (those that don't end with _mask.tif).
def brain_images_list(path):
    if not isinstance(path, str):
        raise TypeError('path must be a string')

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        raise ValueError('path must exist: ', path)

    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        raise ValueError('path must be a directory: ', path)

    # Save current directory.
    current_dir = os.getcwd()

    # Change current directory to the one we want to look for.
    os.chdir(path)

    # Get brain images list
    brain_images_lst = glob.glob('*.tif')

    # Restore directory
    os.chdir(current_dir)

    return brain_images_lst
```

How can I do it?

Comment: in ```brain_images_lst = glob.glob('*.tif')``` you're getting all the images.  You need to filter out those that you don't want.

Comment: Yes, I know what I have to do, my problem is that I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `brain_images_lst = [image for image in brain_images_lst if not image.endswith("_mask.tif")]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [glob exclude pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638040/glob-exclude-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it complicated for yourself with the use of `glob.glob` and the need to change directory, do the glob, and change back again.

If you just want the filenames (not full paths), you will be better to use `os.listdir`, which can be done without changing directory:

```
brain_images_lst = [file for file in os.listdir(path)
                    if file.endswith(".tif")
                    and not file.endswith("_mask.tif")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You better get yourself used to using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) whenever working with paths. It is better than using `os.path` in most cases, and your specific task can be easily done by doing:

```
from pathlib import Path

brain_images_lst = [file for file in Path(path).glob("*.tif") if not file.stem.endswith("mask")]
```

The [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) returns `Path` objects so if you just want the names of the files you can change to [`file.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name).

Comment: Nice, I like it. One little thing: this makes a list of `PosixPath` objects, which might be useful as-is, but to match the existing output format (a list of filenames) it could be worth doing instead `[file.name for file in ....]`

Comment: @alaniwi I totally agree. Check-out my note under the code ;)

Comment: Good point -- not sure how I missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a wildcard for glob. So asking to get `*.tif` will also return `*_mask.tif`. To only get `*.tif` you will want to first store the list as you are but then create a list of all `*_mask.tif`. The following code does this

`brain_images_lst2 = glob.glob('*_mask.tif')`

using this we can then remove all `*_mask.tif` from the `*.tif` by using a loop as such:

```
for x in brain_images_lst2:
    brain_images_lst.remove(x)
```

This should then cause `brain_images_lst` to only contain `*.tif` as required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First list all files with tif type in `file_list`

Store only files in `result` list which don't `_mask.tif`

```
import glob

result = []
file_list= glob.glob(r'C:\Users\vishal\Desktop\Stackoverflow\*.tif') 
for file in file_list:
    if  '_mask.tif' in file:
        continue
    result.append(file)
print(result)
```